Memory Leak using Capacitor SQLite with jeep-sqlite and TypeORM
I have an Issue using "@capacitor-community/sqlite": "^5.7.2" with "typeorm": "^0.3.20", and "jeep-sqlite": "^2.7.0".
jeep-sqlite is needed to be able to persist the inMemory DB from @capacitor-community/sqlite (WebStore) into the LocalForage as indexedDB.
My Issue is that the space is increasing by the amount of the whole DB each time I run "saveToStore()"
if (this.sqliteParams.platform === 'web') await this.sqliteParams.connection.saveToStore(sqliteDataSource.dbName);

It seems like the DB inside indexedDB does not get updated, it is adding the whole data into it again and again instead.
Is this a known issue? Or is there something I should know or possibly doing wrong?
I've also submitted an Issue on GitHub.
